# Data extracting

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

can someone help me how to get value of "end" in this code. I am using beautifulsoup here.

```
<div class="number" color="secondary" data-reactid="72" end="4269" start="0" style="display:flex;align-content:space-between;font-size:1.6rem;line-height:2.2399999999999998rem;color:rgb(130, 130, 130);">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the element using key-value. Here your key is the attribute name.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="number" color="secondary" data-reactid="72" end="4269" start="0" style="display:flex;align-content:space-between;font-size:1.6rem;line-height:2.2399999999999998rem;color:rgb(130, 130, 130);">0</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.div["end"])
```

**Output:**

```
4269
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.I just want to tell you that I have already declared r = requests.get(URL) and  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content). And this part of scraping is just a small part of my whole code. So do I need to write this code line again - soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")  ?

Comment: No you do not have to declare this again. You should be able to get it from `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser" )`

Comment: Thanks. I tried etree method. And it worked as well.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is already sucked into `soup`:

soup.div['end']